# Intellij 14 console not respecting ANSI colors

Tags: intellij-idea, logback

I have defined color highlighting in my logback appender configuration:

```
<encoder>
  <pattern>[%thread] %highlight(%-5level) %cyan(%logger{15}) - %msg %n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

However, logs in IDEA Intellij 14 console are still black and white with ANSI color not escaped:

```
[main] [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mo.o.x.XMLConfigurator[0;39m - Loading configuration from XML Document
```

I use OSX 10 (Yosemite). How can I fix it?

Comment: `System.out.println("[main]\u001B[39mDEBUG\u001B[0;39m\u001B[36mo.o.x.XMLConfigurator")` -- is this snippet working for you if you call it from a simple `public static void main`?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Yes, it works in Intellij console. But when I run a test with TestNG plugin it does not.

Comment: It looks like your IntelliJ console is fine (at least, you should have ANSI color set in Settings->Editor->Colors&Fonts->ConsoleColors). The above ANSI escapes work for me both for `main` and TestNG `@Test` both from IntelliJ IDEA console and Linux Mint terminal, however it does not work in Windows console showing raw ANSI escapes pretty much similar to what you're asking above because `cmd` can't handle ANSI escapes. When you're saying _... with a TestNG plugin_, you mean a debug/run configuration in IDEA, not a TestNG run out of IntelliJ IDEA, right?

Comment: Here is my Windows `cmd` output I'm getting both in IntelliJ via Terminal (if it runs Windows `cmd`) and native Windows terminal: `[main]←[39mDEBUG←[0;39m←[36mo.o.x.XMLConfigurator`. All other enviroments work fine. By the way, is Logback really producing the `\x1B` character `←`? At least I cannot see it in your question (hope, it wasn't consumed while posting the question).

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv, yes, I mean Run/Debug configuration. I will try to prepare minimal working example (Java+Logback conf) and paste it here.

Comment: Same problem here. OSX intelliJ 16.01 ANSI working fine in console, but broken in Test output. Also shows incorrectly in TeamCity

Comment: @dzieciou I'm just curious, did you manage it work?

Comment: @LyobomyrShaydariv Unfortunately not

Comment: I almost believe that the output is just missing the `\u001B` character (`←`) right before the `[`. For example, `out.println("\u001B[31mRED\u001B[39mDEFAULT");` works perfectly in my Linux/SSH session, but rendering raw `←[31mRED←[39mDEFAULT` in Windows Console (Windows Console is weak about that; alternatives like ConEmu work perfect). Both of the latter cases really reveal the `\u001B` character unconsumed. If the issue is still relevant for you, you might also try to put `&#x001B;[31mRED&#x001B;[39mDEFAULT` into your `pattern` to test if the `\u001B` character gets rendered in any way.